# Laravel delete link for items within a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, crud

I am attempting to delete an item within a foreach loop. In this loop, there are several images within $property. For each image ($propimg), I want to delete each image using it's id. However the link doesn't work. How do I get it to delete the individual image?

```
 @foreach($property->images as $propimg) 
  <li>{{ $propimg->id }}<br/>{{ $propimg->image_url }}</li> 
  <a href="/property_gallery/{{ $propimg->id }}" data-method="delete">Delete</a> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Doesnt work how? The html is broken? The route is invalid? The controller action fails?

Comment: please be more specific, about your problem, otherwise mention whether you want us to write the full code for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an Ajax request, please try this:

```
$("[data-method='delete']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: $(this).prop("href")
    }).always(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

If you get 500 HTTP error, due to CSRF token mismatch, please add this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": document.cookie.match('(^|; )XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]*)')[2]
    }
});
```